# Insert dictionary in a list of dictionaries in order

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list

```
 [{'FloatVal':Floatm,'StrVal':'Strm'},{'FloatVal':Floatn,'StrVal':'Strn'}...]
```

The sequence are ascending order `Floatm < Floatn < ...` I want to insert a dictionary `{'FloatVal':FloatX,'StrVal':'StrX'}` in the list making the `Floatx` in order. If `Floatm<FloatX<Floatn` then I want the final list to be

```
 [{'FloatVal':Floatm,'StrVal':'Strm'},{'FloatVal':FloatX,'StrVal':'StrX'},{'FloatVal':Floatn,'StrVal':'Strn'}...]
```

What would be the best pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just sort it again, with a suitable key. Python uses a stable sort that is fast for nearly-sorted objects.

```
>>> result =  [{'FloatVal':'Floatm','StrVal':'Strm'},{'FloatVal':'Floatnb','StrVal':'Strnb'}]
>>> result.append({'FloatVal':'Floatna','StrVal':'Strna'})
>>> result
[{'FloatVal': 'Floatm', 'StrVal': 'Strm'}, {'FloatVal': 'Floatnb', 'StrVal': 'Strnb'}, {'FloatVal': 'Floatna', 'StrVal':'Strna'}]
>>> result.sort(key=lambda x: x['FloatVal'])
>>> result
[{'FloatVal': 'Floatm', 'StrVal': 'Strm'}, {'FloatVal': 'Floatna', 'StrVal': 'Strna'}, {'FloatVal': 'Floatnb', 'StrVal':'Strnb'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html) module, or [an existing implementation of the sorted list](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/) that uses this module. With the latter:

```
s = SortedCollection([{'FloatVal':1}, {'FloatVal':2}], key=lambda x: x['FloatVal'])
s.insert({'FloatVal': 1.5})
print(list(s))

[{'FloatVal': 1}, {'FloatVal': 1.5}, {'FloatVal': 2}]
```